$(this).prop('checked', true); only giving focus and not checking the tickbox
I am having some issue with some jquery & jquery-confirm script and need some advice as it's driving me up the wall.
The page is an email preference centre and if someone un-checks a check-box, it will display an "Are you sure" pop up. If they confirm, it un-checks it, if they cancel, it leaves it checked.
So a working script I have is
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
            if (!this.checked) {
           
                 var isConfirmed = confirm("Are you sure you want to unsubscribe? You could miss out on something invaluable!");
                 if (!isConfirmed) {
                 $(this).prop('checked', true);
                 }

            }
            });
        });

But this displays the traditional UI alert/confirm which is not the greatest. I would like something a little more pleasing. So I found https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/ - Great!
However implementing the code:
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
            if (!this.checked) {
            
                $.confirm({
                    title: 'Please confirm',
                    content: 'Are you sure you want to unsubscribe? You could miss out on something invaluable!',
                        buttons: {
                            confirm: function () {
                            $(this).prop('checked', false);
                            },
                            cancel: function () {
                            $(this).prop('checked', true);
                            },
                        }
                });

            }
            });
        });

the call **$(this).prop('checked', true); ** does not check the box, it just gives it focus.
You can see the code in action at https://preference.cogora.com/
Any suggestions ?
I have spent several hours researching online to try and fix this but to no success.

this inside the button callback functions is not the same as this in the .change() function.
